# Dúvida sobre atribuição de variáveis no Ecmascript 5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

A minha dúvida é relacionada ao comportamento de uma variável, uma vez que é atribuído um valor dinâmico nela.

**Por exemplo no código:**

```
var x_position = window.getComputedStyle(elemento).marginLeft;
```

**Dúvida:** toda vez que eu tiver que ler a variável `x_position`, ela vai buscar novamente o valor mais atualizado do window.getComputedStyle ? Ou essa leitura é feita apenas uma vez?

Minha dúvida é específica para o ES5 porque no 6 já temos as constantes.

Comment: Juntei mais um exemplo para simular o que pretendes. Não muda a resposta mas podes usar mais ou menos como sugeriste na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa leitura é só uma vez.

Tens de reler o valor chamando o `window.getComputedStyle` a cada vez. Independente de ser com `var`, `let` e `const`.

O que podes fazer é *getter* que faça o trabalho por ti, e isso sim é JavaScript ES5, portanto não suportado por browsers mais antigos como o IE8.

Exemplo:

```js
var props = {
  get cor() {
    return window.getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor;
  }
}

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(props.cor);
}, 400);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  animation: mudacor 3s infinite;
}

@keyframes mudacor {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```